# how to solve npm ERR code 1 when running npm opensea js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I'm getting multiple errors and I'm really struggling with this for more than 3-4 hours. Because I tried the solutions of those who received this error before, but failed. It would be appreciated if you could help.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ewaR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\ewaR\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! > wyvern-schemas@0.14.1 prepublish
npm ERR! > yarn build
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm WARN skipping integrity check for git dependency ssh://git@github.com/ahultgren/async-eventemitter.git
npm ERR! npm WARN skipping integrity check for git dependency ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git
npm ERR! npm WARN skipping integrity check for git dependency ssh://git@github.com/ProjectOpenSea/wyvern-js.git
npm ERR! npm WARN skipping integrity check for git dependency ssh://git@github.com/frozeman/bignumber.js-nolookahead.git
npm ERR! npm WARN skipping integrity check for git dependency ssh://git@github.com/ProjectWyvern/ethereumjs-abi.git
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@2.2.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated eth-sig-util@1.4.2: Deprecated in favor of '@metamask/eth-sig-util'
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@1.3.7: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@1.7.1: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-vm@2.6.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/vm. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-common@1.5.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/common. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated axios@0.17.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\ewaR\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneViKlSY
npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c yarn build
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\ewaR\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-12T03_31_24_992Z-debug-0.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ewaR\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-12T03_31_23_039Z-debug-0.log^
```

Comment: If you can add more detail as to what you are doing when your error occurs and what outcome you are hoping to achieve if successful then people will have more understanding of your issue and be able to help you quicker. You may need to edit your questions and add the code that that is causing you this error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is from installing opensea-js with a newer version of Nodejs. I had this same exact issue and I downgraded to Node v14.7.* (I believe) and it resolved my issue. Opensea-js is running on an old version of node for some reason, which is why it's causing this issue.